# Ngrx select return undefined

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have this project to which I am implementing ngrx to handle the states, I am new to this and so far I have managed to create the state and the reducer, but when I try to do the select it returns undefined. This is my code:

This is the action file

```
import { Action, createAction } from '@ngrx/store'
import { ProductCart } from './../models/productCarts.model'

export const ADD_PRODUCTCART = 'Add ProductCart';
export const UPDATE_PRODUCTCART = 'Update ProductCart';

export class AddProductCart implements Action {
  readonly type = ADD_PRODUCTCART
  constructor(public payload: ProductCart) { }
}

export class UpdateProductCart implements Action {
    readonly type = UPDATE_PRODUCTCART
    constructor(public payload: ProductCart) { }
  }

export type Actions = UpdateProductCart | AddProductCart;
```

This is my reducer

```
import { ProductCart } from './../models/productCarts.model';
import * as ProductCartActions from './counter.actions';

const initialState: ProductCart[] = [];

export function taskReducer(
  state: ProductCart[] = initialState,
  action: ProductCartActions.Actions
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ProductCartActions.ADD_PRODUCTCART:
      return [...state, action.payload];
    case ProductCartActions.UPDATE_PRODUCTCART:
      let index = state.map(review => review.id).indexOf(action.payload.id);
      return [
          ...state.slice(0, index),
          Object.assign({}, state[index], {
            quantity: action.payload.quantity
          }),
          ...state.slice(index + 1)
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

My AppState

```
import { ProductCart } from './productCarts.model';

export interface AppState {
  readonly productCart: ProductCart[];
}
```

And finally my component

```
task: Observable<ProductCart[]>;
  constructor(
    private productService: ProductService,
    private store: Store<AppState>
  ) {
    this.task = this.store.select<any>('productCart');
this.task.suscribe(x => console.log(x)) //undefined
```

Also my app.module.ts

```
import { taskReducer } from './shared/ngrx/counter.reducer';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({tasks: taskReducer}),
```

Comment: To debug, do `this.store.subscribe(state => console.log(state))` to see the structure of your store. I bet `productCart` will not be there and that's why you are getting undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `StoreModule.forRoot` is expecting an `ActionReducerMap<AppState>` so export one here including your `productCart` reducer

```
import { ProductCart } from './productCarts.model';
import { taskReducer } from './shared/ngrx/counter.reducer';

export interface AppState {
  readonly productCart: ProductCart[];
}

//export all reducers for app.module.ts StoreModule.forRoot
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
  productCart: taskReducer,
  //add more reducers here
};
```

And in `app.module.ts` a slight change

```
import { taskReducer } from './shared/ngrx/counter.reducer';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { reducers } from 'where-you-export-reducers'

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
   AppComponent
 ],
 imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   AppRoutingModule,
   BrowserAnimationsModule,
   MatIconModule,
   StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
```